# Camel bean component invokes cached instance of @Named / @Dependent bean

Tags: apache-camel

In our application we are using Apache Camel with `camel-cdi` component in JBoss EAP 7.1 environment. After upgrade of Apache Camel to actual version the application started to behave incorrectly in parallel execution.

I have found, that bean component invokes always the same instance. From my understanding, bean with `@Dependent` scope should be always fresh instance for every CDI lookup.

I have tried endpoint parameter `cache=false`, which should be default, but the behavior stays the same. Also tried to specify `@Dependent`, which should be default too.

Attaching MCVE, which fails on Apache Camel `2.20.0` and newer. Works well with `2.19.5` and older. Full reproducible project [on Github](https://github.com/bedlaj/camel-dependent-bean).

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Startup
@ContextName("cdi-context")
public class MainRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:test")
                .to("bean:someDependentBean?cache=false");
    }
}

@Named
//@Dependent //Dependent is default
public class SomeDependentBean implements Processor {
    private int numOfInvocations = 0;
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeDependentBean.class);

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        log.info("This is: "+toString());
        numOfInvocations++;
        if (numOfInvocations!=1){
            throw new IllegalStateException(numOfInvocations+"!=1");
        } else {
            log.info("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do in our application to change this behavior and use actual version of Apache Camel?

**EDIT:**

Removing tags `camel-cdi` and `jboss-weld`. I have created unit test, to simulate this situation without dependencies to camel-cdi and Weld. This test contains assertion to test `JndiRegistry#lookup`, which returns correct instance. According this test I believe, the issue is in bean component itself. Fails with version >=`2.20.0` and passes with <=`2.19.5`

```
public class CamelDependentTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    private Context context;
    private JndiRegistry registry;

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:in")
                        .to("bean:something?cache=false");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
        JndiRegistry registry = super.createRegistry();
        registry.bind("something", new SomeDependentBean());
        this.context = registry.getContext();
        this.registry = registry;
        return registry;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFreshBeanInContext() throws Exception{
        SomeDependentBean originalInstance = registry.lookup("something", SomeDependentBean.class);
        template.sendBody("direct:in",null);
        context.unbind("something");
        context.bind("something", new SomeDependentBean()); //Bind new instance to Context
        Assert.assertNotSame(registry.lookup("something"), originalInstance); //Passes, the issue is not in JndiRegistry.

        template.sendBody("direct:in",null); //fails, uses cached instance of SameDependentBean
    }
}
```

Comment: Created JIRA issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [CAMEL-12610](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12610) is [`Processor`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Processor.html) supposed to be singleton scope. This behavior was introduced in version `2.20.0`. Do not implement [`Processor`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Processor.html) interface, instead annotate invokable method as [`@Handler`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Handler.html).

**Replace**

```
@Named
public class SomeDependentBean implements Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

**with**

```
@Named
public class SomeDependentBean {
    @Handler
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

---

If you cannot afford that as me, because it is breaking behavior for our app extensions, I have implemented simple component. This component have no caching and allows to invoke `Processor` directly from registry.

**CdiEndpoint class**

```
public class CdiEndpoint extends ProcessorEndpoint {
    private String beanName;

    protected CdiEndpoint(String endpointUri, Component component) {
        super(endpointUri, component);
    }

    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onExchange(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Object target = getCamelContext().getRegistry().lookupByName(beanName);
        Processor processor = getCamelContext().getTypeConverter().tryConvertTo(Processor.class, target);
        if (processor != null){
            processor.process(exchange);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("CDI bean "+beanName+" not found");
        }
    }
}
```

**CdiComponent class**

```
public class CdiComponent extends DefaultComponent {
    @Override
    protected Endpoint createEndpoint(String uri, String remaining, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
        CdiEndpoint endpoint = new CdiEndpoint(uri, this);
        endpoint.setBeanName(remaining);
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    getContext().addComponent("cdi", new CdiComponent());
    from("direct:in")
            .to("cdi:something");
}
```

Comment: You should either use a plain POJO with bean, or if you use Camel's `processor` then its singleton scoped and use it via the `.process` EIP.